# Why does file upload give undefined index error?

Tags: php

im using the following to upload an image via html form:

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
</div>
```

php:

```
$folder='images/';
$image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

The error I get is:

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\efarm\admin\index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\efarm\admin\index.php on line 17

What Im I missing there?

edit
here is the cmplete form with unnecessary fields collapsed:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="nme" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat">category:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unit">unit:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="unit" id="unit" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="price">Unit price:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="Quantity" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Image:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="desc">Description:</label>
                    <textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_stock">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: where is your `form`?

Comment: You probably are missing the encoding type on the `form` element.

Comment: here is the complete form with unnecessary inputs collapsed:

Comment: i posted an update to the question with the complete form

Comment: Your form need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to support file upload

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
         your code
}
```